# How does My97DatePicker show Monday to Sunday

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

As shown below I want to display Monday to Sunday.

```
function myWeek() {
    WdatePicker({
        dateFmt : 'DD',
        readOnly : true
    });
}
transfer：onclick="myWeek();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ6GB.png)

Comment: I am not sure what is on you picture. Please provide an English version of it.

Comment: https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/05/21/YbxVPJ.png

Comment: First of all, thank you for your attention. I uploaded a link. I do n’t know if you can see it.